# Move GZ archives with specific content

Tags: command-line, data-recovery, tar

After a restoration of my HDD with PhotoRec I have a folder with 36,500 GZ archives. Of those, around 200 are very important for me.

Each of these archives contains exactly **one** TAR archive. These TAR archives contain folders and among others files of the following file types:

- doc
- docx
- xls
- rtf
- pdf
- ppt
- ods
- odt
- jpg

Is it possible to create a shell script that

1. opens each of these GZ archives
2. checks if there is a TAR archive in it and - if yes
3. opens the TAR archive
4. checks if the TAR archive contains one of the given filetypes and - if yes
5. moves the GZ archive containing the TAR to a given directory

As I am a complete beginner when it comes to shell scripts, I would be very grateful for any hint or pointer in the right direction on how such a script could look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is untested. I've put a safety comment in there (so it just echos the `gz` file rather than moving it) but when you're sure it works, crack on.

```bsh
for f in *.gz; do
    win=$(tar -ztvf "$f" | grep -iE 'doc|docx|xls|rtf|pdf|ppt|ods|odt|jpg$' | wc -l)
    if [[ $win -gt "0" ]]; then
        # mv "$f" /other/directory
        echo "$f contains one of my files!"
    fi
done
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Could I use a similar script to look inside .tar.bz2 files?

Comment: Yeah, change the -z to -j (and the for loop, obviously)